# Multiple application on single PC

Tags: web-server, ip, tomcat, java, windows-server-2019

I have installed **Tomcat server** on my server PC with IP **127.0.0.1**
One application is running on the server. Let address of the application is: *127.0.0.1:8080/first-project* Now if I want to run another application on the same server, address will be: *127.0.0.1:8080/second-project*

I want multiple application with multiple addresses like **127.0.0.1**, **127.0.0.2**

a) Is this possible to have **multiple address on single PC**?

b) What is the best practice for running multiple server on same server?

1. With different IP address (127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.2)
2. With same IP address but different port (127.0.0.1:8080, 127.0.0.1:8081)
3. With same IP different path (127.0.0.1/first, 127.0.0.1/second)

Comment: Since this is obviously a development setup (which is off topic here) this is up to your preference.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this possible to have multiple address on single PC?

You can use the whole 127.0.0.0/8 network locally.
This means all addresses from 127.0.0.1 to 127.255.255.254 are at your disposal.

> What is the best practice for running multiple server on same server?
>
> 1. With different IP address (127.0.0.1, 127.0.0.2)
> 2. With same IP address but different port (127.0.0.1:8080, 127.0.0.1:8081)
> 3. With same IP different path (127.0.0.1/first, 127.0.0.1/second)

Any of these is valid, it totally depends on application architecture/design.
The address would not be accessible remotely anyway, so it's up to you